# Print "*" up to n terms in pattern and its reverse

Tags: c++, reverse

I have a problem that is asking for me to write a C++ program using for loops with less than 3 “cout” statements in your code to print the following pattern (ignore the pipes, the asterisks wouldn't appear without them):

|*

|***

|*****

|*******

|*********

|*********

|*******

|*****

|***

|*

This is my code I used for a fibonacci generator and I feel like it might be similar. I am able to print the "*" symbol but not in horizontal lines. What I need most help with is reversing the output. As in if given number n, I want the series to go n numbers into the series and then back down to 0.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int y = 1, sum = 1, n;

    cout << "Enter the number of terms you want" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    cout << "First " << n << " terms are :- " << endl;

    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {

        cout << "\n" <<endl;


        for (int i = 0; i < sum; i++) {
            cout << "*" << endl;
        } 

        sum = y + 2;
        y = sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: `cout << string('*', k)` will print `k` asterisks in a row, but that's probably not what your teacher wants (there was mention of loops)

Comment: BTW have you learned anything about functions or recursion?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a homework, so I give some hints instead of a full solution.

- For printing the `*`s in one line, please note that `<< endl` will end the line in the output, i.e. print a line break. (The same does `<< "\n"` by the way.) Not every `cout` statement has to have an `<< endl` at its end.
- For reversing the fibonacci sequence, once you have the last number in the variable `sum`, just do the reverse computation (i.e. subtraction). This *could* be done in a second set of loops, however, since you should not use `cout` statements too often, you better *reuse the same loop* by using some additional variable holding the current state (i.e. if you are counting up or down) and using an `if` to decide which computation to do. (I read the requirements such that only the `cout` statements for printing the pattern count to the "less than three" = 2)